# How to forward events from Observable to a PublishSubject?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

So, I have this code in my `ViewModel` and trying to forward the events of `search` to the `publishSubject` so it can be observed in my `ViewController`

Here is my **Repository**

```
func search(origin: String, destination: String, page: Int)-> Observable<[MyObject]>
```

Here is my **ViewModel**

```
let searchObservable: Observable<[MyObject]> { searchPublishSubject.asObservable() }
private let searchPublishSubject = PublishSubject<[MyObject]>()

func search() {
        searchRepository
            .search(origin: origin.value!, destination: destination.value!, page: 1)
            .observe(on: scheduler)
            .subscribe(searchPublishSubject)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Here is the extension function I wrote for the `Observable`

```
func forwardEvents(to publishSubject: PublishSubject<Element>)-> Disposable {
        return subscribe { (element) in
            Log.d("onNext")
            publishSubject.on(.next(element))
        } onError: { (error) in
            Log.d("onError")
            publishSubject.on(.error(error))
        } onCompleted: {
            Log.d("onCompleted")
            publishSubject.on(.completed)
        }
    }
```

Here is my **ViewController**

```
viewModel.search()
viewModel.searchObservable.subscribe { (objects) in
            Log.d("\(objects.count) found")
        } onError: { (error) in
            if let apiError = error.asApiError {
                switch apiError {
                    default:
                        Log.e("Internal error maybe \(error)")
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("Client error \(error)")
            }
        } onDisposed: {
            Log.d("onDisposed")
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

The confusion exposed in your question is around the various overloads for the `subscribe` operator. In one part of your code you are using:

```
viewModel.searchObservable.subscribe { (objects) in
    Log.d("\(objects.count) objects found")
}
```

Which won't compile because the `Event` type doesn't have a `count` method. It seems as though you are assuming that the closure will fill in the `onNext` parameter of the `.subscribe(onNext:onError:onCompleted:onDisposed:)` operator. It won't. Instead the code will use the `subscribe(_ on: @escaping (Event<Element>) -> Void)`.

In another piece you have:

```
extension ObservableType {
    func forwardEvents(to publishSubject: PublishSubject<Element>)-> Disposable {
        return subscribe { (element) in
            Log.d("onNext")
            publishSubject.on(.next(element))
        } onError: { (error) in
            Log.d("onError")
            publishSubject.on(.error(error))
        } onCompleted: {
            Log.d("onCompleted")
            publishSubject.on(.completed)
        }
    }
}
```

(I added a bit more code so it would compile.) Here you seem to be under the assumption that if you want to forward all three event types, you need to pass in three closures. You don't. There is also a `subscribe(to:)` overload that take a subject.

Instead, I suggest you just do:

```
searchRepository
    .search(origin: origin.value!, destination: destination.value!, page: 1)
    .observe(on: scheduler)
    .subscribe(to: searchPublishSubject)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Then you won't need your custom `forwardEvents(to:)` operator.

Lastly...

> Subjects provide a convenient way to poke around Rx, however they are not recommended for day to day use... Instead of using subjects, favor the factory methods...

-- [Intro To Rx](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/02_KeyTypes.html#KeyTypes)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the problem is in my `ViewController` the closures is not getting called. It's like it is not getting observed.

Comment: Well your view controller example code doesn't compile as it sits so that _can't_ get called. Maybe if you posted a compilable example? (Not all the real code, just make it so your example code compiles.)

Comment: I have updated the question with the compiling code.

Comment: Hey! I have a question if an observable threw an error for some reason then it is going to get disposed right? Then we cannot observe it for more?

Comment: Correct. Once an Observable emits an error, it's done. Nothing more will come out of it. This feels very much like the question you asked earlier where I went back and forth with you about adding `debug`s. I don't think Stack Overflow is the correct place for this discussion. Join the RxSwift slack and let's talk about it there. https://rxslack.herokuapp.com